# Is possible treeView inside treeView in odoo

Tags: group-by, treeview, odoo

i want to display treeview inside line_ids.
look picture.
group by  is  sale.order field /line sale.order.line/
[image]

How to decision?

Comment: i think no, but u can build it use kanban oder privot

Comment: Everything is possible! But if you mean with uncustomized odoo framework: No.

Comment: do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Old fashoned tree view:

[image: Old Tree View]

To get this view you have to define action with view_type="tree" f. e.

```
<record id="res_partner_action_form" model="ir.actions.act_window">
  <field name="name">Partners</field>
  <field name="res_model">res.partner</field>
  <field name="view_type">tree</field>
  <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
  <field name="help" type="html">
    <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
    </p>
    <p>
    </p>
  </field>
</record>
```

Tree view definition looks the same as normal one. The diffrence is that here you can use parent_id.

```
<tree string="Account Reports Hierarchy">
  <field name="name"/>
  <field name="type"/>
  <field name="parent_id" invisible="1"/>
  <field name="account_report_id"/>
</tree>
```

Comment: And as additional info: this kind of view was dropped in Odoo 11 and IIRC won't come back in Odoo 12.